# Is it possible to click button without ID in a WebView?

Tags: android, html, webview, click

I have a WebView in my Android app. I want to click the button which does not have ID. Only class. Is it possible to do it also if webview is opening in a browser (another app)?

Comment: can you do it with JavaScript ? cause if you can, it is possible. How many buttons share the class in the same page ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Can you clarify? Do you want the app to trigger a click on the button or do you want the app to do something when the button is clicked. Please clarify your requirements (perhaps with some code showing what you've tried so far).

Comment: you're going to have to show some code.  Is it possible to differentiate elements with only classes from other elements with that same class... but you need to show code; otherwise, it's like you're asking us to create an example from scratch